# WAS 7.0 - default interceptors in MDBs

Tags: java, jms, websphere, interceptor, message-driven-bean

I'm having problems advising MDBs with default interceptors in Websphere 7.0 AS. I have tested the same code using Glassfish  AS and it works fine. The strange thing is that WAS interceptor is applied for stateless beans but not for MDB.

```
<assembly-descriptor>
<interceptor-binding>
    <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>  
    <interceptor-class>jms.service.interceptor.IncomingJMSMessageLogInterceptor</interceptor-class> 
</interceptor-binding>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interceptors are only supported for MDBs using JCA message endpoints, not listener ports.

[APAR PM53989](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM53989) has been opened for this problem.

Comment: I was using MDBs with listener ports so it is very likely that it is a problem - could you give me some link where I can find any docs regarding this issue because I was googling and found nothing about this restriction

Comment: I also searched for a link, but I couldn't find one, sorry.  It appears to be an oversight in the documentation or implementation, but I'm not sure which.  If you have a support contract, you could open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: I know this question and answers are old now, but I confirm that. I had the same problem, spent a couple of days experimenting and couldn't get my interceptors to work when using listener port. I switched to use Activation Spec in WAS, and just like that they started to work. +1